# I cannot run rpi 3 from 8 battery (14500)

Tags: pi-3, power-supply

I cannot run rpi 3 from 8 battery (14500) 
Series circuits 29.6v. I am convert 29.6v through dc-dc converter (XL4005 DSN5000) to 5v.
The converter output can be 5A. But I cannot take more than 0.5A and rpi 3 cannot start

Here's a link to [converter](https://www.amazon.in/XL4005-DSN5000-adjustable-step-down-current/dp/B00XDU28UO)

Comment: Please add links to the converter you refer to.

Comment: @MatsK The question updated

Comment: The output voltage is tunable.  How have you set the output voltage to 5V?

Comment: @joan There is regulator. Voltage is right. It is [test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPLLX7v6-Bc)  with 4 battery

Comment: Post an image of how its all wired up.

Comment: You have a Volt/Amp meter connected in your youtube video. And by 0,5A do you mean thet the reading on the volt/Amp meter doesn't show more? If that is the case, this show the consumption NOT what the DC/DC can deliver.

Comment: And please use this guide https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting and then you can explain more precisely than "and rpi 3 cannot start".

Comment: This question appears to be only peripherally related to the Pi. It is an E&E question.

Answer (score 1):

When you have that many batteries in series you will have a problem: the system current will be limited by the single cell that is capable of the smallest current.

That said **you may then have a faulty battery in the middle of the pack,** check for that.

Also it could be that such batteries are globally/plainly not capable of supplying the current your system needs.

Answer (score -1):

The PSU recommended is 2.5A for the pi3, so, you'll need to increase the current.

You'll need to find a battery that is suitable to output high current. I know, for example, some 18650 batteries can output 20A on stable discharge.

It will depend on the specific properties of the battery model used.

Comment: I know about it. How to make it? 8 14500 can give enough power?

Comment: I've modified my answer to add more info about it.

Comment: When I connected laptop's power supply  (19v 2A) Result is same

Comment: It is not to increase the current to beyond 2.5A as suggested by @LuisDiaz, it is the opposite, you need to make sure that the current will NOT EXCEED 2.5A if you are connecting the power supply via USB, otherwise  it can cause a draw exceeding the limits of the [polyfuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse) on the microUSB supply jack. Exceeding the limit of the poly fuse will cause the Raspberry Pi to shut down.

Comment: So, if you're using a higher current PSU, and it's not booting, there is another issue. Have you tried to boot without the converter module? (using a regular phone charger)

Comment: @hcheung I use pins 2 and 6

Comment: @LuisDiaz with converter. With 2 different converters. Rpi3 is loading until desktop and reset

Comment: @teren4m, based on your last comment, it sounds more like under current or under supply. Based on your converter info, both current and voltage are adjustable, how do you adjust the current and voltage? The Raspberry Pi need at least 700mA (up to 2.5A) with a 5V supply.

Comment: @hcheung there is regulator for voltage. No for current

Comment: What is the current of your 3.7v 14500mAH battery can supply? In fact you don't need 8 batteries, you only need 3 (3 x 3.7v = 11.1v) and your converter has a voltage drop of about 3v, so it is sufficient to supply 5v output, but your battery probably not be able to supply min 700mA required by the RPI.